# Use multiples elements in array with JS and using MQTT

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mqtt

I'm using mqtt and want to display some data with different topic

So this is my script with one topic like this, it works :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/mqtt/dist/mqtt.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paho-mqtt/1.0.1/mqttws31.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    // Globally initializes an mqtt variable    
    const clientId = 'mqttjs_' + Math.random().toString(16).substr(2, 8)

    
    const host = '***'

    let tabTopic = ["showroom/ABC001/temperature", "showroom/ABC002/temperature"]; //not using yet

    const options = {
            ***
            },
        }

    console.log('Connecting mqtt client')
    const client = mqtt.connect(host, options)

    client.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log('Connection error: ', err)
        client.end()
    })

    client.on('connect', () => {
        console.log('Client connected:' + clientId)
        client.subscribe('showroom/ABC001/temperature', { qos: 0 })

        // Subscribe
    })

    client.on('reconnect', () => {
        console.log('Reconnecting...')
    })

    client.on('message', (topic, message, packet) => {
        console.log('Received Message: ' + message.toString() + '\nOn topic: ' + topic);
        Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("svg > text")).forEach((element) => {
            element.textContent = element.textContent.replace("showroom/ABC001/temperature", message.toString());

        });
    })

</script>


<body>
   <svg>
    <text style="font-family: &quot;Roboto Slab&quot;; font-size: 11px; font-weight: 900; white-space: pre;" x="167.376"
        y="4.014">{showroom/ABC001/temperature}</text>
    <text style="font-family: &quot;Roboto Slab&quot;; font-size: 11px; font-weight: 900; white-space: pre;" x="376.274"
        y="9.483">{showroom/ABC002/temperature}}</text>
    </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

So know what I want to do, it's to use the tabTopic array and change the hard coded topic, so I'm trying this:

```
client.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log('Connection error: ', err)
    client.end()
})

for (let i = 0; i < tabTopic.length; i++) {
    const selectedTopic = tabTopic[i];
    client.on('connect', () => {
        console.log('Client connected:' + clientId)
        client.subscribe(selectedTopic, { qos: 0 })

        // Subscribe
    })

    client.on('reconnect', () => {
        console.log('Reconnecting...')
    })

    client.on('message', (topic, message, packet) => {
        console.log('Received Message: ' + message.toString() + '\nOn topic: ' + topic);
        Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("svg > text")).forEach((element) => {
            element.textContent = element.textContent.replace(selectedTopic, message.toString());

        });
    })
}
```

So the problem is that display me the same first result for all elements in my array

Actual result :

- 24
- 24

Expected result:

- 24
- 26

Don't understand why, if someone can help me :)

Comment: where is the opening `svg` tag?

Comment: Wasn't this exact same question asked (and apparently deleted?) jut yesterday? 

Comment: Yes sry I decided to delete and give more details in this one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop for over the `tabTopic` array really isn't doing what you think it is.

Setting the on `connect`, `reconnect` and `message` callbacks multiple times won't do anything sensible.

You should loop over the list of topics once in the on `connect` callback to call `client.subscribe()` once for each topic.

You then need to include logic in the on `message` callback to do different things for each messages type based on what the value of the passed in `topic` parameter.

Comment: If I understand I need to insert my loop for inside the on connect. And I don't understand what do you mean by 'include logic' ?

Comment: There will only ever be one on `message` callback, this needs to be able to handle ALL the incoming message, by checking what topic the current message arrived on.